# Inheritance from parent class return attribute error

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

Hi I tried to inheritance some code from a class :

```
class MathParent:
    def multiply(self, number1, number2):
        self.answer = number1 * number2
        return self.answer
    def happy(self):
        return "Nice Mark!"

class MathChild(MathParent):
    def plus_x(self, x) :
        return self.answer + x

p_out = MathParent()
print(p_out.multiply(5, 2))
print(p_out.happy())

c_out = MathChild()
print(c_out.happy())
print(c_out.plus_x(5))
```

that happy methods has successfully inherited, but when I access self.answer attribute, it raise error. I use another way :

```
return MathParent.self.answer + x
```

And that still didn't work. Any insight will be very helpful :)

Comment: What answer are you expecting to add 5 to? The one from `p_out`? `p_out` is a different object with separate instance attributes.

Comment: p_out(5, 2) ? it will be 10 because 5 * 2

Answer (score 0):

`self.answer` is only declared whenever `multiply` is called. You can add constructors as harshraj22 states, but within the existing code, you need to call `multiply` before calling `plus_x`.

This:

```py
c_out = MathChild()
print(c_out.happy())
c_out.multiply(1, 1)
print(c_out.plus_x(5))
```

runs without errors.

Comment: umm, but when i run, the answer become 6 because 1 * 1 = 1 and then 1 + 5 = 6. I expect 15 because 5 * 2 = 10 and then 10 + 5 = 15

Comment: `p_out` and `c_out` refer to two separate objects. If you want to use the result from `p_out`, instantiate it as an instance of `MathChild` and then call `.multiply(5, 2)` and `.plus_x(5)` on it.

Comment: ah I see.. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

`self.answer` variable is created only when `multiply` function is run.
One way to fix this is, you can use the following to make sure the variable is created once the `__init__` is called:

```
class MathParent:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.answer = 0

    def multiply(self, number1, number2):
        self.answer = number1 * number2
        return self.answer
    def happy(self):
        return "Nice Mark!"

class MathChild(MathParent):
    def plus_x(self, x) :
        return self.answer + x

p_out = MathParent()
print(p_out.multiply(5, 2))
print(p_out.happy())

c_out = MathChild()
print(c_out.happy())
print(c_out.plus_x(5))
```

Comment: umm, but when i run, the answer become 5? I expect 15 because 5 * 2 = 10 and then 10 + 5 = 15

Comment: @JLz18191 `p_out` and `c_out` are two diffferent objects. `multiply()` was done on `p_out`. 
`print(c_out.multiply(5, 2))` add this before `c_out.plus_x(... )` to get expected output. Do `print(p_out.answer)` and `print(c_out.answer)` to understand better

Comment: Thank you very much. I thought '__init__' isn't very useful :)